# Flush stdin (consume entire text and continue when multiline is pasted)

Tags: c, stdin, flush

When I run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void flush_stdin(void)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

static int scand(int *val, int min, int max)
{
    char s[32], *p = NULL;
    long x = 0;

    if (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)) {
        x = strtol(s, &p, 10);
        if (strchr(p, '\n') == NULL) flush_stdin();
    }
    if (p == NULL || *p != '\n' || x < min || x > max) {
        *val = 0;
        return 0;
    } else {
        *val = (int)x;
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int x;

    do {
        printf("Number (1-10): \n");
    } while (scand(&x, 1, 10) == 0);
    printf("Number = %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

And I paste the following text:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I give this output:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Number (1-10):
Number (1-10):
Number (1-10):
```

`printf("Number (1-10): \n");` is processed for each line pasted.

It is possible to eat (flush) the entire text before the return of `scand()` in order to process only one `printf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your terminal is in non-canonical mode, you could use `fgetc` to read in advance and/or `read` to read characters in advance and output the `Number (1-10):` only when buffers are empty and thus you can be sure the user has not typed (or copy&pasted) further lines of text.

Answer (score 1):

The reason only one line is being flushed is because in your flush_stdin() function you're checking for both \n and EOF. Modified to

```
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF);
```

will consume all three lines.

Comment: @ahnlak Then you'll have to wait for EOF `ctrl+D` or `Ctrl+Z`

Comment: You're right, of course - my bad, I was mentally thinking in terms of raw mode.

Comment: @ahnlak, `while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);`